# Purpose of max_inline_action_size?

Tags: permissions, inline-action, msig

What is the practical purpose of max_inline_action_size in global settings?

I was attempting to create a contract that would be set with contract@eosio.prods / contract@eosio.code active permissions to update itself based on user provided and voted abi/code via inline_actions (setabi/setcode); then I learned about the "max_inline_action_size".

Feels like a hindrance ( if you want to make the contract immutable but also modifiable due to a bug or any severe eosio changes ). I considered msig, but the voters with the right to vote or propose an abi/code would dynamically change day to day; I don't think the msig would work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_inline_action_size is one of a few blockchain_paramaters allowing to protect the network. Unlimited inline_action_size is a potential attack-vector and could be used by malicious actors to harm the network.

If you take a look at the configured max_inline_action_size on different chains and compare it with the size of typical .wasm and .abi-files it should be enough for most cases while I see that there could be a problem with very very large contracts.